# How do I calculate the metric Cumulative Gain,...?

Tags: python, recommender-system

I am currently in the process of creating a recommender system. Here I use a neural network and then I use k-means to find the closest neighbors and thus show the user 20 recommended articles.
I would like to use the Cumulative Gain (CG), Discounted Cumulative Gain (DCG) and  Normalized Discounted Cumulative Gain (NDCG) metrics. I also found the following [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/evaluate-your-recommendation-engine-using-ndcg-759a851452d1) and the following [implementation of scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ndcg_score.html).

```
from sklearn.metrics import ndcg_score
>>> # we have groud-truth relevance of some answers to a query:
>>> true_relevance = np.asarray([[10, 0, 0, 1, 5]])
>>> # we predict some scores (relevance) for the answers
>>> scores = np.asarray([[.1, .2, .3, 4, 70]])
>>> ndcg_score(true_relevance, scores)
```

We speak of `true_relevance` and `scores` here. How do I get this? Are these my `y_test` and `y_train`, or do I only get these values ​​after using the k-means algorithm? Can someone help me on how to get this data so that I can calculate the metrics? (If something is missing, please let me know)

**Dataframe**:

```
d = {'purchaseid': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9],
     'itemid': [ 3, 8, 2, 10, 3, 10, 4, 12, 3, 12, 3, 4, 8, 6, 3, 0, 5, 12, 9, 9, 13, 1, 7, 11, 11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

   purchaseid  itemid
0           0       3
1           0       8
2           0       2
3           1      10
4           2       3
```